# Typeahead with API call in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, typeahead

I need to use Typeahead to add the global search in app , when user type it should call api and show result in drop-down , i am new to angular and typescript , let me know if there any working example with code. i am using angular 10 version

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

There are many libraries you can use.

```
  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(() => this.searching = true),
      switchMap(term =>
        this.tagService.searchByKeyword(this.category, term).pipe(
          tap(() => this.searchFailed = false),
          catchError(() => {
            this.searchFailed = true;
            return of([]);
          }))
      ),
      tap(() => this.searching = false)
    )
```

```
<input class="form-control" [placeholder]="placeholder" [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="change($event)" [ngbTypeahead]="search" [readonly]="readonly">
```

Something like this.